# Java reading a string from file not equal to itself

Tags: java, string, filepath

I am new to programming and I cannot for the life of me figure out why aa does not equal bb in the following. I need to extract a file path string from a text file of settings. I read in the 9th line from a txt file as a string like so to get the path:

```
String content = new Scanner(new File("settingsfilepath.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
String[] textStr = content.split("\n");

aa = textStr[9];
bb = "testpath";

    if(aa.equals(bb)){
        print("Contents of both strings are same");
    }else{
        print("Contents of strings are different");
    }

print(textStr[9]);
print(bb);
```

OUTPUT when printing `aa is: testpath`

OUTPUT when printing `bb is: testpath`

RESULT: `"Contents of strings are different"`

I need the variable aa to equal the string bb because when I use a save function [savefunction(filetype,filepath);]

somesavefunction(filetype,aa);    error problem with path

somesavefunction(filetype,bb);    this works

Are there two different types of strings? Maybe I am not reading in the file path from the text file as a string properly? I feel so stupid :( I hope this question makes sense as I had a hard time trying to explain it in this post.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: try using `aa.trim().equals(bb.trim())`, it might have whitespaces

Comment: You're sure you don't need `textStr[8]`?

Comment: Trim did the trick! I can't believe I spent hours on that.  Thank you so so much, I survived with a couple strands of hair left on my head.

Comment: I added it as an answer @paul :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you have white space, try using `trim()` and change your condition to

```
aa.trim().equals(bb.trim())
```

Comment: Trim only removes whitespace. Typo?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do a

```
System.out.printf("aa = '%s', bb = '%s'%n", aa, bb);
```

I suspect there is white space in one or both strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 9th line is what you want, you should set aa to the 8th array element as arrays have a zero-based index.

```
aa = textStr[8];
```